# How to add the json2html library to a typescript project?

Tags: json2html

I am currently using webpack 5 * and installing this package with the team
npm install node-json2html as per instruction
на https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json2html

> Errors occur during project assembly
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '../webpack-typescript/node_modules/node-json2html'
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vm' in '..s/webpack-typescript/node_modules/node-json2html'
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in './webpack-typescript/node_modules/node-json2html'

Add npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack

But now work